# How Can I Check For The Existence of a UUID

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am trying to check for the existence of a UUID as a primary key in my Django environment...and when it exists...my code works fine...But if it's not present I get a "" is not a Valid UUID...

Here's my code....

```
uuid_exists = Book.objects.filter(id=self.object.author_pk,is_active="True").first()
```

I've tried other variations of this with .exists() or .all()...but I keep getting the ['“” is not a valid UUID.'] error.

I did come up with a workaround....

```
    if self.object.author_pk is not '':
        book_exists = Book.objects.filter(id=self.object.author_pk,is_active="True").first()
        context['author_exists'] = author_exists
```

Is this the best way to do this?  I was hoping to be able to use a straight filter...without clarifying logic....But I've worked all afternoon and can't seem to come up with anything better.  Thanks in advance for any feedback or comments.

Comment: Why is `.author` not a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Thanks for the response.  I could be wrong but from what I've read you have to store the UUID as a Charfield if you're referencing it from a different field.   So I store it as a Charfield in one table and then try to compare it a different model to see if it exists.  It's a UUID on the primary model...and I then use a Charfield to store it on another field.  If there's a better way I'm open to it.

Comment: @SteveSmith ```It's a UUID on the primary model``` can you please tell me which model are you referring to here? author or book?

Comment: Book is where I am checking for the UUID.  The author_pk is what I’m trying to use to see if the Book UUID matches the author_pk.  In this case the author_pk is null…so when I the filter runs I get a “” is not a Valid UUID.  That’s why my workaround works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and this is what I have:
Wrapping it into try/except (in my case it's a View so it's supposed to return a `Response` object)

```py
try:
    object = Object.objects.get(id=object_id)
except Exception as e:
    return Response(data={...}, status=status.HTTP_40...
```

It gets to the exception (4th line) but somehow sends `'~your_id~' is not a valid UUID.` text instead of proper data. Which might be enough in some cases.

This seems like an overlook, so might as well get a fix soon. *I don't have enough time to investigate deeper, unfortunately.*

So the solution I came up with is not ideal either but hopefully is a bit cleaner and faster than what you're using rn.

```py
# Generate a list of possible object IDs (make use of filters in order to reduce the DB load)
possible_ids = [str(id) for id in Object.objects.filter(~ filters here ~).values_list('id', flat=True)]

# Return an error if ID is not valid
if ~your_id~ not in possible_ids:
    return Response(data={"error": "Database destruction sequence initialized!"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

# Keep working with the object
object = Objects.objects.get(id=object_id)
```